# Restoring only part of Windows Registry backup (From Regback Folder)

Tags: windows, hive, registry, regedit

So Windows takes a periodic backup of the HKLM Registry hives and stores them in the C:\Windows\System32\Config\RegBack folder and I'm in a position where I need to restore only a sub-key of the SOFTWARE hive (As the file has been restored from a file-system backup from a few weeks ago), however I'm unsure how to go about doing this rather than having to restore the entire SOFTWARE hive.

If I Load in the restored SOFTWARE file on another machine I can browse the entries, but they have to be in a uniquely named Key/Hive/Folder, and if I export the sub-key (And all of it's sub-keys) that I want then any attempt to re-import it will only import it to that temporary unique name from when I loaded the Hive.

Short of exporting this way and then manually changing the path of all the sub-keys in the exported .reg file I'm not sure how else I can possibly do this. Is there something I'm missing that anyone else might know?

Comment: .reg files do not include the security descriptor nor class names. Be careful if importing something by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a program that calls `RegLoadKey` and then `RegCopyTree`. This should preserve the security descriptors unlike a .reg file.

With PowerShell you can do `Copy-Item -Path 'HKLM:\mybackup' -Destination 'HKLM:\foo\bar' -Force -Recurse` but I don't know if this copies all HKEY details or just the names and values.

Comment: Looks like that's going into Windows App development which is somewhat outside my area of expertise.

Is there any kind of Powershell equivalent?

Comment: You can call them from Powershell but you still need a fair bit of win32 experience. You don't HAVE to call RegLoadKey, you can use Regedit if this is a one time thing. If you wanted something simple you should have asked on SuperUser.com ;)

Comment: It is just a one time thing that I need to do. I was trying to use regedit but couldn't find any way to do what I wanted from the GUI options.

Comment: You can load a key in regedit but you still need the powershell code I posted. You might not need all the extra details, just name and value. It would help if you told us which key you want to restore. System or Software\Microsoft you have to be a little careful, other things is probably fine with simple solutions.

Comment: The Key I'm looking at is a non-Microsoft Key under Software, Software\Altiris

I'll give a try to that Powershell code to see if it copies what we need. Thanks!

Comment: Ah darn, using Copy-Item it copies the first few entries, then hits a `Copy-Item : Requested registry access is not allowed`   I have local admin rights on the machine and my powershell prompt is open as Administrator.

Comment: In Regedit, try to change the permissions and replace on all children of Software\Altiris (possible in the permissions dialog).